# Wi-FI logon page doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I'm trying to connect to the Wi-Fi network at a hotel. Instead to be redirected to login page, the error 404 pops-up in the browser. 
What I have tried to do is following:

1. introducing router's IP in three different browsers (Google Chrome, Internet Explorer and Edge); the same 404 error shows
2. delete IE browser history and also temp files from my computer
3. proxy settings to be unchecked
4. to don't have a dynamically IP
5. to forget the network and after that to connect again
6. ipconfig /flushdns command in cmd
7. Use the following DNS Server address: 8.8.8.8, alternative 8.8.4.4

Using my mobile phone everything works fine, I connect to the network, the login page appears into the browser, I introduce the credentials and the internet works.

Can somebody tell me what else can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to manually go to the captive portal - try to navigate to captive.apple.com (not org, sorry) on your browser (a generic captive portal for Apple devices), or try to go to the hotels own website.

Comment: My phone is an Apple device, and the connection works fine on it, what it doesn't work is my laptop with win10 installed.

Comment: Yes, so try and manually navigate to captive.apple.com* (not org, sorry) on your windows 10 browser

Comment: The message "success" appears in my browser. How can it help me?

Comment: that usually means it's authenticatwd your device. Try and browse the Web now, see if it works. Otherwise, perhaps try another browser like Firefox or Chrome